# Mostrar lista de nombres sin repetir nombre

Tags: mysql, java-ee

Deseo ver la lista de nombres que no se repiten en dos tablas diferentes:

**Tabla 1 (de nombre "personal")**

```
SELECT * 
FROM personal 
WHERE fecha_trabajo BETWEEN '2023-02-07' AND '2023-02-14'
```

[image]

**Tabla 2 (de nombre "liquidaciones")**

```
SELECT * 
FROM liquidaciones 
WHERE fecha_liquidacion BETWEEN '2023-02-08' AND '2023-02-14'
```

[image]

Los pongo en contexto, en la primera tabla("personal") se registran los datos de las chicas que trabajan diariamente, y en la segunda tabla("liquidaciones") se registran los datos de cada chica que se la paga los turnos de trabaja, siempre se registran de martes a martes. Si una chica trabaja solo 3 dias se la hace la liquidación de esos 3 dias.

Entonces, lo que deseo es ver la lista de nombres de las chicas que faltan por liquidar quitando el ultimo nombre que se liquide. Si en la semana trabajaron 20 chicas y ya se liquido a la primera chica necesito mostrar el nombre de las otras 19 chicas que faltan y asi sucesivamente, esto lo hago consultando siempre la tabla "liquidaciones".

Si hago una consulta por separado como en las imágenes los datos son correctos, pero no se como crear una consulta `SQL` para que me muestre la lista de nombres de las chicas que faltan por liquidar usando los datos de las 2 tablas.

Agradezco la ayuda, este es mi primer post.....

Comment: Hola Edward, bienvenido, te sugiero que agregues tu código como texto, para que podamos ayudarte, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla

Comment: Gracias Marce. Esta es la consulta que estoy usando pero no me sirve: SELECT nombre, COUNT(*) FROM `personal` WHERE nombre NOT IN (SELECT nombre from liquidaciones) AND fecha_trabajo BETWEEN '2023-02-08' AND '2023-02-14' GROUP by nombre ORDER by nombre ASC

Comment: Hola, intenta con `SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM YourTable` a ver si es lo que estas buscando

Comment: Luis, MySQL ha devuelto un conjunto de valores vacío (es decir: cero columnas). (La consulta tardó 0.0028 segundos.)

Comment: Intenta con `SELECT p.* FROM personal p LEFT JOIN liquidaciones l ON l.nombre = p.nombre AND l.fecha_liquidacion between ... WHERE l.id is null AND p.fecha_trabajo between ...`.